# Delta-Star Combination Exercise

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistance, delta, star

This post is regarding exersise 4-8 from the following book:
*Hughes Electrical And Electronics Technology 10th Ed.*

Here it is:

[image]

Let's focus on what I tried for solving **part (b)** :

Since this is an exercise under the chapter for *delta-star transformations* my first thought was to try and perform some such transformation. However this was a combination of both star and delta connections so I didnt really know whether the resulting resistances would be in series / parallel or neither, with the already existing ones, so I tried both series and parallel:
[image]

However neither worked.

My next thought was that maybe I have understood something very badly about the *resulting* resistance of two points in a circuit. So after a little bit of digging I tried the following:
[image]

However I again got a wrong result in regards to the given answers at the end of the book.

Conclusion:

- Which approach (if any) was correct?
- If no approach was correct, which concept do I need to understand better?

Any help/hint is very much appreciated

Comment: I don't think any of your approaches makes sense and also  you didn't explain anything how you draw these equivalent circuits

Comment: Take the delta, transform into a star. You have two start in parallel which is easy to simplify. Or take the star. transform into a delta. Two deltas in parallel. Or both, transform  the final delta into a star (or vice versa) to check you get the same answer.

Comment: @BrianDrummond this is what it tried(first picture), i guess i made some computational error, will try again

Comment: @BrianDrummond I have concluded that i have not made any computational mistake, the resulting Resistance from A to N turn out to be 0.98 ohm with this method, which by the book is wrong, it should be 1.45 ohms

Comment: @BrianDrummond it worked for part (a) however so I am clearly doing somethiing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate equivalent resistance between A and N one approach would be -

1.look at NCB which is in Delta connected form

2.make NCB in star connection from delta by conversion formula

after that conversion you'll get a very simlified circuit which is very easy to solve

Comment: I see what you mean, and it worked, I posted the full solution as an answer here. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, this is the answer for part(b) "Finding Equivalent resistance from A to N".

First of all, here is a nicer sketch:

[image]

Now we will focus at the *delta* connection defined by **N** , **B** , **C** :

[image]

And now if we go back to our original sketch and replace the converted circuit we can greatly simplify it:

[image]

Finally, we are ready to compute the equivalent resistance from A to N:

[image]